# API Time is converted in a weird way in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

There is an external API connecting to a SFMC DE.

I've got a DE set up with a date/time field

Here's an example of a snippet of our payload coming through

```
[
 {
      "Transaction_Start_DateTime":"2020-12-12T02:00:00.0000000Z",
      "Transaction_Complete_DateTime":"2020-12-11T18:13:58.7046319Z"
 }
]
```

The times come through in SFMC like so:

Transaction_Start_DateTime - Friday, December 11, 2020, 8:00 PM
Transaction_Complete_DateTime- Friday, December 11, 2020, 11:39PM

The time difference doesn't seem consistent- any suggestions on how to address this?